# Symfony Elasticsearch criteria

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

I want to filter post criteria:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (title LIKE '%AA%' OR subtitile LIKE '%BB%') AND category = 'Car'
```

What I try:

```
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.website.article');
$boolQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Bool();

$fieldQuery = new \Elastica_Query_Text();
$fieldQuery->setFieldQuery('title', '*keyword*');
$fieldQuery->setFieldParam('title', 'analyzer', 'my_analyzer');
$boolQuery->addShould($fieldQuery);

$fieldQuery1 = new \Elastica_Query_Text();
$fieldQuery1->setFieldQuery('subtitle', '*keyword*');
$fieldQuery1->setFieldParam('subtitle', 'analyzer', 'my_analyzer');
$boolQuery->addShould($fieldQuery1);

$fieldQuery2 = new \Elastica_Query_Text();
$fieldQuery2->setFieldQuery('category', 'Car');
$boolQuery->addMust($fieldQuery2);

$data = $finder->find($boolQuery);
```

I get ALL post of 'Car' category and some of this post contains 'keyword', but I need have only post of 'Car' category what contais keyword 'keyword' but not ALL

How to fix my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace both `addShould` with `addMust`.

I also recommend using https://github.com/ongr-io/ElasticsearchBundle instead of https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle :)